# Calling a function to apply discounts before submitting the form in VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to apply corresponding discounts to each item in my campaign.items before submitting my form with Axios.

**For this, I have a function that works correctly:**

```
  applyDiscount(price) {
    return price - (this.totalDiscount * price)
  },
```

**I'm placing the function call inside my submit function before submitting:**

```
 methods: {
  submit() {
    this.campaign.items.forEach(function(item) {
        this.applyDiscount(item.price)
    }),
    var data = new FormData()
```

**I'm getting the error:**

`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'applyDiscount')"`

Comment: I _really_ hope this is just to display the discount & discounted price to the user. Because if this is where you apply the discount and compute the final price I will be setting a breakpoint in your code and forcing `applyDiscount()` to return `0` every time.

Comment: Yes, I'm calculating the discounts in the backend , just showing the discount rate in frontend. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `this` inside of your anonymous function isn't the same as `this` outside of it.  Typically what you can do is to get a reference to `this` before, by doing `let that = this;` and then use `that` inside of the other function:

```js
class Demo {
    applyDiscount() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    example() {
        var that = this;
        [1,2].forEach(function() {
            that.applyDiscount();
        })
    }
}

let x = new Demo();
x.example()
```

or you can bind this:

```js
class Demo {
    applyDiscount() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    example() {
        [1,2].forEach((function() {
            this.applyDiscount();
        }).bind(this))
    }
}

let x = new Demo();
x.example()
```

or you can use an arrow function:

```js
class Demo {
    applyDiscount() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    example() {
        [1,2].forEach(() => {
            this.applyDiscount();
        })
    }
}

let x = new Demo();
x.example()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done the same, I suppose the "global" `this` is not equal to the component `this`.

An arrow function should work,

```js
 methods: {
  submit() {
    this.campaign.items.forEach((item) => {
        this.applyDiscount(item.price)
    }),
    var data = new FormData()
```